# CSS3 parallax bug in IE8 and 9

Tags: jquery, css, slider, slideshow, parallax

I am modifying this parallax CSS3 slider code that I got from http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/03/15/parallax-content-slider-with-css3-and-jquery/.

It works in ff, chrome, ie10 ..but in **IE 8/9** i got a misplace of the image like you can see here: http://cl.ly/image/3M2Y3Z3D422L

the live code for this is here: http://bit.ly/14q3U6d

The css code is here: http://bit.ly/19vlneC

```
.da-slider{
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 520px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: transparent url(../images/slider_bg.png) no-repeat 0% 0%;

}
.da-slide{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; height:
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    font-family:'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
}
.da-slide-current{
    z-index: 1000;
}
.da-slider-fb .da-slide{
    left: 100%; 
}
.da-slider-fb  .da-slide.da-slide-current{
    left: 0px;
}
.da-slide h2,
.da-slide p,
.da-slide .da-link,
.da-slide .da-img{ 
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0; left:0;
    left: 110%; 
}
.da-slider-fb .da-slide h2,
.da-slider-fb .da-slide p,
.da-slider-fb .da-slide .da-link{
    left: 44%;
    opacity: 1;
}
.da-slider-fb .da-slide .da-img{
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}
.da-slide h2{
    color: #fff;
    /*width: 50%;*/
    top: 50px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 10;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    font-family:laurenscriptregular; font-size:30px; font-weight: 700; font-stretch:semi-condensed; padding-top:10px!important; height:40px!important; 
}
.da-slide p{
    width: 45%;
    top: 100px;
    color: #2e0c02;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    height: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-style: italic;
    position:inherit;
    z-index:120;
}
.da-slide .da-img{ 
    text-align: center; 


}
.da-slide .da-link{
    top: 180px; /*depends on p height*/
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border: 4px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    padding: 2px 20px 0px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    position:inherit;
    z-index:130;
}
.da-slide .da-link:hover{
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
.da-dots{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    left: -140px;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 1000;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}
.da-dots span{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #e4b42d;

    margin: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 
        1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1) inset, 
        1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}
.da-dots span.da-dots-current:after{
    content: '';
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(246,246,246,1) 47%, rgba(237,237,237,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(47%,rgba(246,246,246,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(237,237,237,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(246,246,246,1) 47%,rgba(237,237,237,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(246,246,246,1) 47%,rgba(237,237,237,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(246,246,246,1) 47%,rgba(237,237,237,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(246,246,246,1) 47%,rgba(237,237,237,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ededed',GradientType=0 );

}
.da-arrows{
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}
.da-arrows span{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #e4b42d;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 2000;
    opacity: 0;
    box-shadow: 
        1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1) inset, 
        1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out 0.2s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out 0.2s;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out 0.2s;
}
.da-slider:hover .da-arrows span{
    opacity: 1;
}
.da-arrows span:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    background: transparent url(../images/arrows.png) no-repeat top left;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.da-arrows span:hover:after{
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.da-arrows span:active:after{
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}
.da-arrows span.da-arrows-next:after{
    background-position: top right;
}
.da-arrows span.da-arrows-prev{
    left: 15px;
}
.da-arrows span.da-arrows-next{
    right: 15px;
}

.da-slide-current h2{
    left: 44%;
    opacity: 1;
}
.da-slide-current .da-img{
    left: 9%;
    opacity: 1;
}
.da-slide-current .da-link {left:60%; opacity: 1;}
.da-slide-current p {left:46%; opacity: 1;}
/* Animation classes and animations */

/* Slide in from the right*/
.da-slide-fromright h2{
    -webkit-animation: fromRightAnim1 0.4s ease-in 0.8s both;
    -moz-animation: fromRightAnim1 0.4s ease-in 0.8s both;
    -o-animation: fromRightAnim1 0.4s ease-in 0.8s both;
    -ms-animation: fromRightAnim1 0.4s ease-in 0.8s both;
    animation: fromRightAnim1 0.4s ease-in 0.8s both;
}
.da-slide-fromright p{
    -webkit-animation: fromRightAnim2 0.6s ease-in 0.8s both;
    -moz-animation: fromRightAnim2 0.6s ease-in 0.8s both;
    -o-animation: fromRightAnim2 0.6s ease-in 0.8s both;
    -ms-animation: fromRightAnim2 0.6s ease-in 0.8s both;
    animation: fromRightAnim2 0.6s ease-in 0.8s both;
}
.da-slide-fromright .da-link{
    -webkit-animation: fromRightAnim3 0.4s ease-in 1.2s both;
    -moz-animation: fromRightAnim3 0.4s ease-in 1.2s both;
    -o-animation: fromRightAnim3 0.4s ease-in 1.2s both;
    -ms-animation: fromRightAnim3 0.4s ease-in 1.2s both;
    animation: fromRightAnim3 0.4s ease-in 1.2s both;
}
.da-slide-fromright .da-img{
    -webkit-animation: fromRightAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.9s both;
    -moz-animation: fromRightAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.9s both;
    -o-animation: fromRightAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.9s both;
    -ms-animation: fromRightAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.9s both;
    animation: fromRightAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.9s both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fromRightAnim1{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 44%; opacity: 1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fromRightAnim2{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 46%; opacity: 1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fromRightAnim3{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    1%{ left: 10%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 60%; opacity: 1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fromRightAnim4{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 9%; opacity: 1; }
}

@-moz-keyframes fromRightAnim1{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 44%; opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fromRightAnim2{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 46%; opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fromRightAnim3{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    1%{ left: 10%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 60%; opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fromRightAnim4{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 9%; opacity: 1; }
}

@-o-keyframes fromRightAnim1{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 44%; opacity: 1; }
}
@-o-keyframes fromRightAnim2{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 46%; opacity: 1; }
}
@-o-keyframes fromRightAnim3{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    1%{ left: 10%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 60%; opacity: 1; }
}
@-o-keyframes fromRightAnim4{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 9%; opacity: 1; }
}

@-ms-keyframes fromRightAnim1{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 44%; opacity: 1; }
}
@-ms-keyframes fromRightAnim2{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 46%; opacity: 1; }
}
@-ms-keyframes fromRightAnim3{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    1%{ left: 10%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 60%; opacity: 1; }
}
@-ms-keyframes fromRightAnim4{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 9%; opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes fromRightAnim1{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 44%; opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes fromRightAnim2{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 46%; opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes fromRightAnim3{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }
    1%{ left: 10%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 60%; opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes fromRightAnim4{
    0%{ left: 110%; opacity: 0; }

    100%{ left: 9%; opacity: 1; }
}
/* Slide in from the left*/
.da-slide-fromleft h2{
    -webkit-animation: fromLeftAnim1 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    -moz-animation: fromLeftAnim1 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    -o-animation: fromLeftAnim1 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    -ms-animation: fromLeftAnim1 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    animation: fromLeftAnim1 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
}
.da-slide-fromleft p{
    -webkit-animation: fromLeftAnim2 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    -moz-animation: fromLeftAnim2 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    -o-animation: fromLeftAnim2 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    -ms-animation: fromLeftAnim2 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    animation: fromLeftAnim2 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
}
.da-slide-fromleft .da-link{
    -webkit-animation: fromLeftAnim3 0.4s ease-in 1.2s both;
    -moz-animation: fromLeftAnim3 0.4s ease-in 1.2s both;
    -o-animation: fromLeftAnim3 0.4s ease-in 1.2s both;
    -ms-animation: fromLeftAnim3 0.4s ease-in 1.2s both;
    animation: fromLeftAnim3 0.4s ease-in 1.2s both;
}
.da-slide-fromleft .da-img{
    -webkit-animation: fromLeftAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    -moz-animation: fromLeftAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    -o-animation: fromLeftAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    -ms-animation: fromLeftAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    animation: fromLeftAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fromLeftAnim1{
    0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 44%; opacity: 1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fromLeftAnim2{
    0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 46%; opacity: 1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fromLeftAnim3{
    0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
    1%{ left: 10%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 60%; opacity: 1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fromLeftAnim4{
    0%{ left: -30%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 9%; opacity: 1; }
}

@-moz-keyframes fromLeftAnim1{
    0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 44%; opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fromLeftAnim2{
    0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 46%; opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fromLeftAnim3{
    0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
    1%{ left: 10%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 60%; opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fromLeftAnim4{
    0%{ left: -30%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 9%; opacity: 1; }
}

@-o-keyframes fromLeftAnim1{
    0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 44%; opacity: 1; }
}
@-o-keyframes fromLeftAnim2{
    0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 46%; opacity: 1; }
}
@-o-keyframes fromLeftAnim3{
    0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
    1%{ left: 10%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 60%; opacity: 1; }
}
@-o-keyframes fromLeftAnim4{
    0%{ left: -30%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 9%; opacity: 1; }
}

@-ms-keyframes fromLeftAnim1{
    0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 44%; opacity: 1; }
}
@-ms-keyframes fromLeftAnim2{
    0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 46%; opacity: 1; }
}
@-ms-keyframes fromLeftAnim3{
    0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
    1%{ left: 10%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 60%; opacity: 1; }
}
@-ms-keyframes fromLeftAnim4{
    0%{ left: -30%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 9%; opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes fromLeftAnim1{
    0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: 44%; opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes fromLeftAnim2{
    0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 46%; opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes fromLeftAnim3{
    0%{ left: -110%; opacity: 0; }
    1%{ left: 10%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 60%; opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes fromLeftAnim4{
    0%{ left: -30%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 9%; opacity: 1; }
}
/* Slide out to the right */
.da-slide-toright h2{
    -webkit-animation: toRightAnim1 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    -moz-animation: toRightAnim1 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    -o-animation: toRightAnim1 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    -ms-animation: toRightAnim1 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    animation: toRightAnim1 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
}
.da-slide-toright p{
    -webkit-animation: toRightAnim2 0.6s ease-in 0.3s both;
    -moz-animation: toRightAnim2 0.6s ease-in 0.3s both;
    -o-animation: toRightAnim2 0.6s ease-in 0.3s both;
    -ms-animation: toRightAnim2 0.6s ease-in 0.3s both;
    animation: toRightAnim2 0.6s ease-in 0.3s both;
}
.da-slide-toright .da-link{
    -webkit-animation: toRightAnim3 0.4s ease-in both;
    -moz-animation: toRightAnim3 0.4s ease-in both;
    -o-animation: toRightAnim3 0.4s ease-in both;
    -ms-animation: toRightAnim3 0.4s ease-in both;
    animation: toRightAnim3 0.4s ease-in both;
}
.da-slide-toright .da-img{
    -webkit-animation: toRightAnim4 0.6s ease-in both;
    -moz-animation: toRightAnim4 0.6s ease-in both;
    -o-animation: toRightAnim4 0.6s ease-in both;
    -ms-animation: toRightAnim4 0.6s ease-in both;
    animation: toRightAnim4 0.6s ease-in both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes toRightAnim1{
    0%{ left: 44%;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes toRightAnim2{
    0%{ left: 46%;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes toRightAnim3{
    0%{ left: 60%;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes toRightAnim4{
    0%{ left: 9%;  opacity: 1; }
    30%{ left: 60%;  opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}

@-moz-keyframes toRightAnim1{
    0%{ left: 44%;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes toRightAnim2{
    0%{ left: 46%;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes toRightAnim3{
    0%{ left: 60%;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes toRightAnim4{
    0%{ left: 9%;  opacity: 1; }
    30%{ left: 60%;  opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}

@-o-keyframes toRightAnim1{
    0%{ left: 44%;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-o-keyframes toRightAnim2{
    0%{ left: 46%;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-o-keyframes toRightAnim3{
    0%{ left: 60%;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-o-keyframes toRightAnim4{
    0%{ left: 9%;  opacity: 1; }
    30%{ left: 60%;  opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}

@-ms-keyframes toRightAnim1{
    0%{ left: 44%;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes toRightAnim2{
    0%{ left: 46%;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes toRightAnim3{
    0%{ left: 60%;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes toRightAnim4{
    0%{ left: 9%;  opacity: 1; }
    30%{ left: 60%;  opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes toRightAnim1{
    0%{ left: 44%;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes toRightAnim2{
    0%{ left: 46%;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes toRightAnim3{
    0%{ left: 60%;  opacity: 1; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes toRightAnim4{
    0%{ left: 9%;  opacity: 1; }
    30%{ left: 60%;  opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: 100%; opacity: 0; }
}
/* Slide out to the left*/
.da-slide-toleft h2{
    -webkit-animation: toLeftAnim1 0.6s ease-in both;
    -moz-animation: toLeftAnim1 0.6s ease-in both;
    -o-animation: toLeftAnim1 0.6s ease-in both;
    -ms-animation: toLeftAnim1 0.6s ease-in both;
    animation: toLeftAnim1 0.6s ease-in both;
}
.da-slide-toleft p{
    -webkit-animation: toLeftAnim2 0.6s ease-in 0.3s both;
    -moz-animation: toLeftAnim2 0.6s ease-in 0.3s both;
    -o-animation: toLeftAnim2 0.6s ease-in 0.3s both;
    -ms-animation: toLeftAnim2 0.6s ease-in 0.3s both;
    animation: toLeftAnim2 0.6s ease-in 0.3s both;
}
.da-slide-toleft .da-link{
    -webkit-animation: toLeftAnim3 0.4s ease-in both;
    -moz-animation: toLeftAnim3 0.4s ease-in both;
    -o-animation: toLeftAnim3 0.4s ease-in both;
    -ms-animation: toLeftAnim3 0.4s ease-in both;
    animation: toLeftAnim3 0.4s ease-in both;
}
.da-slide-toleft .da-img{
    -webkit-animation: toLeftAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    -moz-animation: toLeftAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    -o-animation: toLeftAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    -ms-animation: toLeftAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
    animation: toLeftAnim4 0.6s ease-in 0.6s both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes toLeftAnim1{
    0%{ left: 44%;  opacity: 1; }
    30%{ left: 15%;  opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes toLeftAnim2{
    0%{ left: 46%;  opacity: 1; }
    30%{ left: 15%;  opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes toLeftAnim3{
    0%{ left: 60%;  opacity: 1; }
    99%{ left: 10%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes toLeftAnim4{
    0%{ left: 9%;  opacity: 1; }
    90%{ left: -110%;  opacity: 0; }
}

@-moz-keyframes toLeftAnim1{
    0%{ left: 44%;  opacity: 1; }
    30%{ left: 15%;  opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes toLeftAnim2{
    0%{ left: 46%;  opacity: 1; }
    30%{ left: 15%;  opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes toLeftAnim3{
    0%{ left: 60%;  opacity: 1; }
    99%{ left: 10%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes toLeftAnim4{
        0%{ left: 9%;  opacity: 1; }
    90%{ left: -110%;  opacity: 0; }
}

@-o-keyframes toLeftAnim1{
    0%{ left: 44%;  opacity: 1; }
    30%{ left: 15%;  opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-o-keyframes toLeftAnim2{
    0%{ left: 46%;  opacity: 1; }
    30%{ left: 15%;  opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-o-keyframes toLeftAnim3{
    0%{ left: 60%;  opacity: 1; }
    99%{ left: 10%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-o-keyframes toLeftAnim4{
    0%{ left: 9%;  opacity: 1; }
    90%{ left: -110%;  opacity: 0; }
}

@-ms-keyframes toLeftAnim1{
    0%{ left: 44%;  opacity: 1; }
    30%{ left: 15%;  opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes toLeftAnim2{
    0%{ left: 46%;  opacity: 1; }
    30%{ left: 15%;  opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes toLeftAnim3{
    0%{ left: 60%;  opacity: 1; }
    99%{ left: 10%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes toLeftAnim4{
    0%{ left: 9%;  opacity: 1; }
    90%{ left: -110%;  opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes toLeftAnim1{
    0%{ left: 44%;  opacity: 1; }
    30%{ left: 15%;  opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes toLeftAnim2{
    0%{ left: 46%;  opacity: 1; }
    30%{ left: 15%;  opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes toLeftAnim3{
    0%{ left: 60%;  opacity: 1; }
    99%{ left: 10%; opacity: 0; }
    100%{ left: -50%; opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes toLeftAnim4{
    0%{ left: 9%;  opacity: 1; }
    90%{ left: -110%;  opacity: 0; }
    }
```

and the html code (I don;t think here will be any issue) looks like this:

```
        <div id="main_right">


          <div id="da-slider" class="da-slider">

            <div class="da-slide">
                <h2>Banner Caption</h2>
                <p>Vestibulum erat nisl, semper id posuere eleifend, mollis in ipsum. Cras facilisis tincidunt ante id egestas. </p>
                <a href="#" class="da-link">Read more</a>
                <div class="da-img">
                    <img src="images/slider_img1.png" alt="image01" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="da-slide">
                <h2>Banner Caption2</h2>
                <p>Vestibulum erat nisl, semper id posuere eleifend, mollis in ipsum. Cras facilisis tincidunt ante id egestas. </p>
                <a href="#" class="da-link">Read more</a>
                <div class="da-img">
                    <img src="images/slider_img1.png" alt="image01" />
                </div>
            </div>


            <nav class="da-arrows">
                <span class="da-arrows-prev"></span>
                <span class="da-arrows-next"></span>
            </nav>

        </div>


    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Update: jsFidle link for this: http://jsfiddle.net/6tJCm/

Answer (score 0):

I'm on mac..so testing in IE is a little hard for me ..but I found this solution on my issue:

```
.da-slide-current .da-img{
    left: 9%;

    opacity: 1;
}
```

Change the right initial position of the image / or any other element in css/ in all line

maybe this will help someone else